# Position div relative to another div that isn't its parent

Tags: html, css

Hi i'm looking at a site for a client who is using a prebuilt theme. Unfortunately at mobile window size the recent articles links after click reloads the page making it look as though nothing has changed/happened but infact the content it loads is waaaaayyyy down at the bottom of the page. Not very user friendly

I would like to know if its possible to somehow position the content it loads after click to beneath recent articles and above categories? Looking at the html setup the div for the recent articles and the div container for the content it loads are separated so there is no parent for it to position to.

http://www.contentstorelondon.com/blogs/news

Any help would be massively appreciated because i'm really stuck with it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: no problem thanks for that i'll try to create a working snippet example that is effectively the same issue